# Unable to change layout programmatically

Tags: android, layout

I am making an Application where I have multiple screens.

Initially, i thought of using an Image View inside a relative layout and changing its background source but it does not work.

Then I created a new layout and set its background source. When i use setContentView(R.layout.xx) Still it does not worked.

This is happening in only some sections of my code. Not in every section.

Not able to find a solution.

Code :

```
buttonForm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Log.d("Socket","Entered User Details " );
        Log.d("Socket","Name : " + editName.getText());
        Log.d("Socket","Number : " + editNumber.getText());
        Log.d("Socket","Email : " + editEmail.getText());
        myClient.msg = "one";
        msg = "one";
        //  setContentView(R.layout.basic);
        while(true) {
            Log.d("Socket","Waiting for ok " );
            try {
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(1000);
                }
            }
            catch(InterruptedException ex){
            }
            if ((myClient.mainresponse.contains("ok"))) {
                myClient.msg = "ready";
                Log.d("Socket","Received OK");
               // setContentView(R.layout.tablet3); -> here tablet 3 is a xml layout 
                ImageView layout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
                layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.tablet2); // -> here tablet 2 is a image in drawable 
              //  getWindow().getDecorView().findViewById(android.R.id.).invalidate();
                break;
            }
        }
        countryPicker();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this.**

```
ImageView layout = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.background);
layout.setImageResource(R.drawable.tablet2);
```

Comment: No Succes :(. I am not able to understand why it is not changing

Answer (score 0):

imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_all_out_black_24dp));

you need to set ImageDrawable rather than ImageResource

Comment: No, not working. When I click the button it does everything inside, somehow jus skips this line. layout.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.tablet2));

Comment: May be myClient.mainresponse does not contain "ok"

Comment: okay.. intialise your imageview outside maybe.. out of this click event

Comment: well, i am able to see "Received OK" in logs. That means it gets inside this check. Here is GitHub Link : https://github.com/navaljoshi/QatarFly . Its in MainActivity

Answer (score 0):

Wow, your code is really bad, You are doing it all wrong (**Short answer at the bottom**, but you probably must read the following):

1. You are running a `while(true) {...}` loop on the UI thread, meaning that you are blocking the UI thread, this alone might be the reason of why things are not working for you (e.g. changing layouts). (Note that button onClick listeners will be called by UI Thread).
2. Again, You are using `wait()` call, which also will blocks the UI thread. please do not do that!
3. Using synhronized(this) meaning that you are synchronizing the whole this object, in your case the this is the activity. I see no reason why doing this, only in case your app creates multiple instances of the same activity, which i don't think that is your case.
4. I see that adding ImageView like this is most likely wrong: `layout.setBackgroundResource(yourImageView)`, you need to add views to layout using `layout.addView(yourImageView);` (you might need to set the image view layout params to present it as you want).

**Short answer:**

So, dynamically calling `setContentView(R.layout.tablet3);` should work!
It's all the other bad things I mentioned above that causes your code not to work!

**Right approach:**

It seems that you need to run work on either a background thread or AsyncTask, there the thread can wait for something to happen (`myClient.mainresponse.contains("ok")` in your case), When this happens you can always invoke work on the UI thread, like this:

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() { /* Do UI work, like changing layout */ }
});
```